# Wordpress login through facebook not working properly

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I am trying to login via Facebook into a wordpress site. I used all the keys correctly and followed the steps as per facebook post. But i get the same message. I even updated the URI to white-listed.

> URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

Comment: your redirect URL is not correct in facebook APP settings

Comment: Are you trying to login to a Wordpress application that you control?